# Javascript autogenerating getters for corresponding property name issue

Tags: javascript

Hi I do not understand behavior...

```
 var myObject = {};

 for (prop in obj){
    var fnName = "get" + prop;
    myObject[fnName] = function(){
       return obj[prop];
    };
}
```

I have object "obj" containing properties which have objects assigned. For each property I want to create "get" + name of property function and assign it to "myObject". Everything is fine except that, when I call

```
myObject.getXXXA();
myObject.getXXXB();
myObject.getXXXC();
```

I receive the same object for each "getXXX()" method. Returned object is the one which was iterated as last one in "for (prop in obj)" loop. It is like "prop" variable in function body "return obj[prop];" was changed for every already assigned function.

Could someone explain me that behaviour please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful of defining closures inside a loop. The inner closure closes over the *variable*  prop , *not* over its value. (Therefore all the props are always the same value, since they use the same variable. In the end props is the last object).

Have a function maker function so you can create a new custom prop variable for each method.

```
function make_getter(p){
    return function(){
        return obj[p];
    };
}

for(prop in obj){
    myObjec['get' + prop] = make_getter(prop);
}
```

This problem also often happens when someone tries to use an `i` from the for(;;) loop in a closure.